# Joining a collection to the same collection name. (MongoDB Query)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to join a collection to itself with a different $match used?

I have below the same used case

Data:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "transactioncode" : "testtransactAA", "staffcode" : "staffA1", "isactive" : true }
{ "_id" : 2, "transactioncode" : "testtransactBB", "staffcode" : "staffB1", "isactive" : true }
{ "_id" : 3, "transactioncode" : "testtransactCC", "staffcode" : "staffC1", "isactive" : false }
{ "_id" : 4, "transactioncode" : "testtransactCC", "staffcode" : "staffC2", "isactive" : false }
{ "_id" : 5, "transactioncode" : "testtransactDD", "staffcode" : "staffD1", "isactive" : true  }
{ "_id" : 6, "transactioncode" : "testtransactEE", "staffcode" : "staffE1", "isactive" : true  }
{ "_id" : 7, "transactioncode" : "testtransactEE", "staffcode" : "staffE2", "isactive" : false }
```

I want to display all unique transaction code and in the staff code there will be a condition that:

- If isactive is true, show the staffcode
- If a transaction code consist of 1 or more staffcode, show only staffcode who has isactive: true
- If a transaction code consist of 1 or more staffcode that have both isactive : false, make it null

Output will be:

```
{ "transactioncode" : "testtransactAA", "staffcode" : "staffA1"}
{ "transactioncode" : "testtransactBB", "staffcode" : "staffB1"}
{ "transactioncode" : "testtransactCC", "staffcode" : null}
{ "transactioncode" : "testtransactDD", "staffcode" : "staffD1"}
{ "transactioncode" : "testtransactDD", "staffcode" : "staffE1"}
```

My code here is i am trying to rejoin the same table name but it is only getting documents that have isactive:true and ignoring those documents that have staffcode with both false status

```
{
runCommand: {
    aggregate: "operationsmonitoring",
    pipeline: [


{ $lookup: { from: 'operationsmonitoring', localField:'_id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'getIsactive' } },
     { $unwind: { path: '$getIsactive', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
     {$match:{'getIsactive.isactive':true } },

                {
    $project:{
"transactioncode":"$transactioncode",
"staffcode":"$staffcode"

            }
                }
],

"cursor": {batchSize:100000}
```

}
}

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sub-pipeline in `$lookup` to lookup `isActive:true` record only.

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zJieaKu5JRt) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you!.  Another question. would it be possible to $unwind inside this pipeline? In case there will be index before defining $expr?

Comment: You mean putting a $unwind inside the sub-pipeline? I dont understand as your sample collection does not have an array field by itself.

Comment: Yes. Not in this sample actually. I am thinking that if in the future I will encounter sub-pipeline that needs to be $unwind first before making the $expr/$cond

Comment: Just think the sub-pipeline as operating a pipeline on the lookup collection. Common performant practices on a pipelines (e.g. putting $match first ) applies to sub-pipelines too. If those $unwind helps, of course you can apply it to sub-pipelines too.